# Catching exceptions within asyncio coroutine

Tags: python, exception, coroutine, aiohttp, python-asyncio

I have a script to download files  using asyncio. The problem I am facing is when an exception is rised, it is catched within the task but the task is resumed and start the loop again

In **downloader** a loop for pagination has been implmented, the inner loop **attemps** stop after 3 attemps and to stop the outer loop **pagging** an exception is rised and catched in **except ...** At that point the coroutine should return but instead of that the loop **attemps** start again but this time with a value = 2

This behaivor only happen when several tasks (the coroutne **downloader**) run at the *same time* (when several tasks are submitted to the loop) If the coroutine run one by one the the coroutine has the spected behaivour

```py
async def downloader(session, url, spe_params, path, name, writer,
                     max_features=5000, sleeping=5):
    try:
        pagging = True
        while pagging:
            attemps = 3
            while attemps:
                # attemps reduced for looping
                try:
                    async with session.get(url, params=p) as res:
                        if res.status != 200:
                            raise aiohttp.ClientError
                        res_json = await res.json()

                except (aiohttp.ClientError, asyncio.TimeoutError,
                        json.JSONDecodeError) as e:
                    message = 'Error fetching {0}'.format(str(e))
                    attemps -= 1
                    await asyncio.sleep(sleeping)
                else:
                    if res_json['totalFeatures'] == number_returned:
                        pagging = False
                        break
                    # Here the logic for pagination

            if not attemps:
                # attemps have been consumed
                # Pagination stops and raise exception
                raise DownloadError(message)

    except DownloadError as e:
        # Exception is catched. The coroutine should end but instead of that
        # the loop "attemps" start again with the original value - 1

    else:
        # Json written to file

async def main():
    loop_tasks = []
    for id in field_id:
        task = loop.create_task(downloader(session, ... )

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(loop_tasks,
                                               return_when='ALL_COMPLETED')
```

Comment: *coroutine should return* - I don't see any `return` in your code

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest return is not needed since there is not more code after the except catching

Comment: this code is so difficult to read!  why are you raising exceptions only to immediately catch them?  why have those nested while loops?  at least you're now using `asyncio.wait`, but why specify the documented default value?  also `raise` interrupts execution and hence having anything after it, i.e. the `break`, is pointless